# Client-side validation is not firing on my custom BaseValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, ajaxcontroltoolkit

So, I'm writing a custom validator to validate the Ajax Toolkit's Rating control.  The client side validation isn't firing, though.

I have this method to register the script:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    string script = @"<script type=""text/javascript"">function RatingValidatorEvaluateIsValid(val)
{
    alert( 'here' );
    return false;
}</script> ";

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "ratingValidator", script);
}
```

And I register the attribute like this:

```
protected override void AddAttributesToRender(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);

    // Add the client-side code (if needed)
    if (this.RenderUplevel)
    {
        writer.AddAttribute("evaluationfunction", "RatingValidatorEvaluateIsValid", false);
    }
}
```

The script appears on the page, as well as the attribute, but the `alert('here')` never appears.

(Everything works fine, Server-side)

**Edit** Markup:

```
<ajaxToolkit:Rating ID="ajaxRating" runat="server" StarCssClass="ratingStar" WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar" 
                FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar" CssClass="stars"
                RatingAlign="Horizontal" RatingDirection="LeftToRightTopToBottom" 
                AutoPostBack="True" OnChanged="OnChanged" />
<my:RatingValidator runat="server" ID="RatingValidator" ControlToValidate="ajaxRating"
ErrorMessage="Please select a rating." EnableClientScript="True"
</my:RatingValidator>
```

**Edit 2** Okay, this is weird...

The `span` that gets generated is proper:

```
<span id="CPHUser_rating_RatingValidator" evaluationfunction="RatingValidatorEvaluateIsValid" style="visibility:hidden;">Please select a rating.</span>
```

But the JS at the bottom doesn't have my evaluationfunction assigned.

```
var CPHUser_rating_RatingValidator = document.all ? document.all["CPHUser_rating_RatingValidator"] : document.getElementById("CPHUser_rating_RatingValidator");
CPHUser_rating_RatingValidator.controltovalidate = "CPHUser_rating_ajaxRating";
CPHUser_rating_RatingValidator.errormessage = "Please select a rating.";
```

Comment: Silly question - but do you have your `ControlToValidate` property defined on the validator? That for one thing can cause nothing to happen.

Comment: Have you tried to see if only the alert would fire.. try something like this string strMessage = "Hello World" string script = "alert('" + strMessage + "');";
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true); then see if it will actually trigger the message.. then take it from there to make sure that your control to validate is assigned to some validator.. does this make sense..?

Comment: @KP - Yes it is.  Would you like to to include my view?

Comment: @DJKRAZE - When I tried that, I get the alert as soon as I hit the page... So the JS is there, but just not firing when I try to submit.

Comment: @MattGrande - yeah it would be helpful to show your markup for sure.

Comment: also curious why you are using a Literal @ in your script not that it would hurt but you're using forward slashes "/" in not back Slashes "\" when describing your script text type would need to see more code I believe also OnPreRender are you sure that is where you want the script to be fired..? I am not aware of your specs for this ...just curious

Comment: @DJKRAZE - I used the @ to allow a multi-line string, that's all.  I pust it in the OnPreRender because I was following [this article](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092006-1.aspx), but it was written back in 2006, so who knows if it's still accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I answered my own question...

I was apparently assigning my `evaluationfunction` incorrectly.

I've changed it to this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute(this.ClientID, "evaluationfunction", "RatingValidatorEvaluateIsValid");
```

and now it works.

Thanks for your help, guys!